# Flutter: Try adding a return statement, or changing the return type to 'void'

Tags: flutter

I have this widget and it gives me

This function has a return type of 'Widget', but doesn't end with a return statement.
Try adding a return statement, or changing the return type to 'void'.

```
...List.generate(_userSocialInfo.length, (index) {
                if (index != 0) {
                  IconButton(
                    icon: FaIcon(
                      _socialIcon[index],
                      color: Colors.orange,
                      size: 40,
                    ),
                    onPressed: _socialFunction[index],
                  );
                }
              }),
```

I've tried to add  everywhere possible. However, it seems like I can not get that blue underline away. How can I make sure the widget returns void?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this code:

```
...List.generate(_userSocialInfo.length, (index) {
            if (index != 0) {
              return IconButton(
                icon: FaIcon(
                  _socialIcon[index],
                  color: Colors.orange,
                  size: 40,
                ),
                onPressed: _socialFunction[index],
              );
            }
            return Container(height: 0);
          }),
```